# How can I receive notifications that a cocoa binding value has changed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

I am just learning Cocoa Bindings, but I have hit a snag. Is there a way to invoke a method when the value of a binding changes?

**Example:**

I am binding an `NSStepper` to `NSUserDefaults` to set an int, but I need to be able to update some other things when the int is changed. Is there a way to receive a notification directly from the object controller? Or should I somehow be observing the `NSStepper`?
If so, how do I go about that? IB doesn't seem to like me messing with it when its already bound.

Comment: If you can provide few more information

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Key Value Observing (KVO)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to observe NSUserDefaults directly. Sign up for notifications like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"YourUserDefaultsKey" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Then implement this, and it will be called whenever the value for `@"YourUserDefaultsKey"` changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (object == userDefaults && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"YourUserDefaultsKey"]) {
        int intValue = [userDefaults intValueForKey:@"YourUserDefaultsKey"];
        // Do whatever you need to do with new intValue
    }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to unregister as an observer wherever it's appropriate (e.g. in `-dealloc`):

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"YourUserDefaultsKey"];
}
```

Note that Cocoa Bindings itself is based on KVO.

Disclaimer: I typed all the code in this answer in the browser. It should be correct, but may have a typo or two.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you can bind more than one control to the same key on NSUserDefaults (or anything else that's KVO compliant). So, if you wanted a text field nest to the stepper displaying the current value, just bind it to the same key and it will be automatically updated when the stepper modifies the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember Notifications, notification center, observers, @selector:, then your work is done.

EDIT:

You can observe the changes of int, through its class. Its upto you, how you are implementing it, though IB or through code.

Comment: I tried setting up an observer for myTextField.integerValue, but It doesn't fire. are there limitations as to what you can observe?